# Unable to access array within an array from Salesforce flow http callout (beta)

Tags: visual-workflow, json, httprequest, array

In sandbox, I am attempting to gather the information from https://data.nasdaq.com/api/v3/datasets/USTREASURY/YIELD.json

I used the beta feature of creating an HTTP callout right from the flow. It creates an external service based on the sample response you provide.

My problem is that within the JSON created, there is an array within an array; because the response is like

```
"data":[["2023-02-02","4.62","4.65","4.66","4.76","4.64","4.09","3.75","3.49","3.44","3.4","3.67","3.55"]],
```

When I access the response from the callout within the flow, the array column_names is available, but not the array data.

The JSON created is:

```
{"openapi":"3.0.1",
 "info":{"title":"dataNasdaqGetRates"
         ,"description":""},
 "paths":{"":{"get":{"description":"",
                     "operationId":"getRates",
                     "parameters":[{"name":"api_key","in":"query","required":true,"allowEmptyValue":false,
                                    "schema":{"type":"string"}},
                                   {"name":"order","in":"query","required":true,"allowEmptyValue":false,
                                    "schema":{"type":"string"}},
                                   {"name":"limit","in":"query","required":true,"allowEmptyValue":false,
                                     "schema":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"}}],
                     "responses":{"2XX":{"description":"",
                                         "content":{"application/json":{"schema":{"type":"object",
                                                                                  "properties":{"dataset":{"type":"object",
                                                                                                           "properties":{"end_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "data":{"type":"array",
                                                                                                                                 "items":{"type":"array",
                                                                                                                                          "items":{"type":"string"}}},
                                                                                                                         "description":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "newest_available_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "type":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "dataset_code":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "column_index":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "frequency":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "oldest_available_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "transform":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "premium":{"type":"boolean"},
                                                                                                                         "refreshed_at":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "database_id":{"type":"integer",
                                                                                                                                        "format":"int64"},
                                                                                                                         "database_code":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "name":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "limit":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},
                                                                                                                         "id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},
                                                                                                                         "column_names":{"type":"array",
                                                                                                                                         "items":{"type":"string"}},
                                                                                                                         "collapse":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "start_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "order":{"type":"string"}
                                                                                                                        }}}}}}}}}}}}
```

I've attempted to tweak the JSON to remove the nested array, hoping it might just work. I've attempted to add additional "type": to the nested array (technically the first item is a string and the rest are integers).

I was expecting there to be another apex-defined list called "data" listed after columnx5fnames; or even just a text collection or anything at all that I could add to a variable and access.
[response items menu from flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6NQ0.png)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in External Services. Open a support case. Workaround: stick the JSON in https://json2apex.herokuapp.com and add a little bit of Apex for callout.